# Saving Results of JOIN clauses Syntax error

Tags: sql

Here is my code, everything works completely except for the INTO part, I want to save my JOIN result table to a new table. Error is "Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword INTO"

```
SELECT --want the results to contain these columns 
  activity.Id,
  activity.ActivityDate,
  steps.StepTotal,
  calories.Calories,
  activity.VeryActiveDistance,
  activity.ModeratelyActiveDistance,
  activity.LightActiveDistance LightlyActiveDistance, -- for consistent column naming --
  intensities.SedentaryActiveDistance,
  activity.VeryActiveMinutes,
  activity.FairlyActiveMinutes,
  activity.LightlyActiveMinutes,
  activity.SedentaryMinutes
INTO
  newtable
FROM
  `fitbit-data-exploration.FitBit_Tracker.daily activity` AS activity
JOIN
  `fitbit-data-exploration.FitBit_Tracker.daily intensities` AS intensities
ON
  activity.Id = intensities.Id
AND
  activity.ActivityDate = Intensities.ActivityDay
JOIN
  `fitbit-data-exploration.FitBit_Tracker.daily steps` AS steps
ON
  activity.Id = steps.Id
AND
  activity.ActivityDate = steps.ActivityDay
JOIN
  `fitbit-data-exploration.FitBit_Tracker.daily calories` AS calories
ON
  activity.Id = calories.Id 
AND
  activity.ActivityDate = calories.ActivityDay;
```

Tried to use INSERT INTO, INSERT, and just INTO. Those three all give syntax errors. If my placement of the INSERT clause if wrong, where should I be putting it?

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Google Bigquery?

Comment: Try without the comments. Try a smaller working example first (like select * into newtable from activity) and  add 1 join at a time till the error occurs. The quoted table name 'fitbit-data-exploration.FitBit_Tracker.daily activity' is suspect.

Comment: Please confirm if you are using either SQL Server or BigQuery.

Comment: he's likely using bigquery because it looks ok on sql server

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags, the correct tag will need to be added in an [edit].

Comment: It's not valid T-SQL either, with those backticks, @siggemannen

Comment: solved: I did ```CREATE TABLE 'fitbit-data-exploration_FitBit_Tracker.daily activity full' as``` and then the rest of my code starting from ```SELECT``` and it worked. I had to define the data set and table